# How to remove bullets on collision in a shooter game?

Tags: arrays, flash, collision

I'm trying to create a flash shooter game as my first project. But I can't remove the bullets and enemies when they are hit or off-screen.
I've searched for a solution on the problem multiple times and copied about 4 of them (plus I've tried my own ideas) but they are not working.
The current method of checking for collisions is:

```
    for each(var enemy:Enemy in basicEnemies)
    {
        for each(var projectile:Projectile in bullets)
        {
            if (projectile.x > enemy.x - enemy.width / 2 && 
            projectile.x < enemy.x + enemy.width / 2 &&
            projectile.y > enemy.y - enemy.height / 2 && 
            projectile.y < enemy.y + enemy.height / 2)
            {
                trace("collision!");
            enemy.enemyHealth = enemy.enemyHealth-5;
            projectile.projectileIsPassive = true;
            }
    }
```

My question is: How can I remove the enemies and bullets? removeChild and splice?
I'd be grateful if this question got answered.

Comment: Why is it you can't remove them? Can't you just remove them from the "bullets" collection the same way you'd add them?

Comment: When I try to remove them (removeChild(bullets[i])) it throws up the error: Parameter child must be non-null.

Comment: Because `bullets[i]` is returning null, just do `removeChild(projectile);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would perform a removeChild and splice them off your container lists. `removeChild(projectile);...`

Comment: [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.

Comment: You're trying to remove something that's already null. Because `bullets[i]` is returning null, just do `removeChild(projectile)`;

Comment: [Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller. Would a method that changes a variable to false as it is in the code box above then sorts depending on the variable and deletes the ones with projectileIsPassive=true work?

Comment: If you're inside the object itself and you want to remove it from the display list, do `if(parent != null) parent.removeChild(this);`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works fine except when I try to remove the enemy:
    if (enemyIsDead == true, parent != null)
    {
        //parent.removeChild(enemy);
    }
When I add the line commented out, it throws an error:information=TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.